# script from Gimp into Android Assets?

Tags: android, eclipse, gimp

I'm looking for a way to shorten the work pipeline from gimp
to textures assets into eclipse, while updating java references
to the individual images.

Ideally, I should be able to edit something in gimp, run a script,
then be able to run as android app.

As it is, I'm not using any scripting between the two programs, 
but If there is an existing solution to automatically update
pixel references and import texture atlases it would dramatically speed
the workflow.

Working in windows 8.

Comment: Narrowing the gap between gimp and Eclipse. Gimp - texture-Atlas-Tools a file detailing coordinates is only generated when a new .png is appended, and not when layers are combined into a texture atlas. I am experimenting with libgdx which has tools to dynamically refer to individual images within an Atlas. Porting the whole game to libgdx is proving a bit hairy, but it could shorten iteration in the long-run.